# Associate a tag with a contact where drupal tables have a prefix using civicrm 5.32.2 - drupal table prefix missing

Tags: contacts, tags, drupal-7

CiviCRM 5.32.2 is missing the drupal 7.77 prefix when trying to access drupal tables that should have the drupal table prefix applied. How can I fix this?  I am using Shoreditch theme, running with PHP 7.3.25, and MySQL server version 5.7.26

This is the error I get when trying to update an individual's record:
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: no such table
Error Details
Database Error Code: Table 'jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_vocabulary' doesn't exist, 1146
Additional Details:

Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => handle
)

```
[code] => -18
[message] => DB Error: no such table
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT  t.tid as category_id, concat( v.name , '-', t.name)  as category_term_name 
             FROM jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_term_data t
             JOIN jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_vocabulary v ON t.vid = v.vid
         GROUP BY t.tid [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_vocabulary' doesn't exist]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SELECT  t.tid as category_id, concat( v.name , '-', t.name)  as category_term_name 
             FROM jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_term_data t
             JOIN jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_vocabulary v ON t.vid = v.vid
         GROUP BY t.tid [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_vocabulary' doesn't exist]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT  t.tid as category_id, concat( v.name , '-', t.name)  as category_term_name 
             FROM jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_term_data t
             JOIN jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_vocabulary v ON t.vid = v.vid
         GROUP BY t.tid [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_vocabulary' doesn't exist]"]
```

)

Return to home page.

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home/customer/www/jandbweb.jandbwebsite.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 93

The table being accessed should be 'jandbweb_jandb78.Jbwtaxonomy_vocabulary' and not 'jandbweb_jandb78.taxonomy_vocabulary'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the contenttokens extension? It doesn't look like it's been updated in a while but you'll need to file an issue with them. These lines need updating to include the prefix:

https://github.com/sgladstone/com.pogstone.contenttokens/blob/0a949241068afe9b34f49ecacfa0a5bf6a13facc/contenttokens.php#L575-L576